# What should the query string look like for KeyValuePair?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

If I have a method setup as:

```
[HttpPut({path})]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(sting path, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> values)
```

What should the query string look like? (i.e. As if I was typing them into a browser to test)

**EDIT:**

I've tried

```
http://localhost:12345/APath?values[0].Key=AKey&values[0].Value=MyValue
```

but receive a 404.

Comment: Can you use an `IEnumerable<string> values` ? 

will let you call in this way: `http://localhost:12345/APath?values=MyValue&values=MyValue2&values=MyValue3`.  
in method Signature you should have: 
`pubic async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(sting path, [FromQuery]string[] values)`

Comment: I would want to be able to enter multiple key/value pairs.

Comment: Like AVal1,Value1 AVal2,Value2 etc...

Comment: for `[PUT]` operations you can use `[FromBody]` attribute. 
for example: 
`[HttpPut({path})]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(sting path, [FromBody]ValuesCollection values)` , where ValuesCollection is a class encapsulating a public Property of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

Comment: don't forget to perform the call to the url `http://localhost:12345/APath` with the `verb` set to `[HttpPut]` and with the `body` set to the a json structured similar to `ValuesCollection`

Comment: hmmm still getting 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post a working example for your guidance:

```
public class MyPerformerController: ApiController {
    [HttpPut("update/{myPath}")]
    public IActionResult PerformUpdate(string myPath, [FromBody]MyDataTransferObject myDto) {

    }
}
```

`public class MyDataTransferObject {
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Pairs { get; set; }
}`

Perform a `PUT` call to: `http://localhost:12345/api/myperformer/update/aPath`

`body`: in json format should be

`{
    SomeProperty: "asd",
    Salutation: "Mr",
    Pairs: [
        {key: 'key1', value: 'value1'},
        {key: 'key2', value: 'value2'},
    ]
}`

Be sure you set the `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: application/json`

**EDIT**
Including a screenshot from Postman (Http Put call)
[image: http put call from postman]

Comment: It was the headers...  ty